# Custom styles on Highcharts legends

Tags: javascript, css, highcharts

I have custom styles on legends of Highcharts which works fine. When I click the item, I want to apply other style to give a disable button impression. To achieve this, I have used counter i.e. when the counter is even, active style should be applied and inactive style should be used on odd counter. This is not working properly, I guess the issue is with scopes. Please find the code below:

```js
var clickCounter = 0;
Highcharts.chart('container', {

    plotOptions: {

        series: {
            events: {
                legendItemClick: function () {
                    clickCounter++;
                    return clickCounter;
                }
            },
            showInLegend: true
        }
    },

    legend: {
        useHTML: true,
        labelFormatter: function (clickCounter) {
          if(clickCounter%2 == 0)
            return '<span class="span-legend-active">' + this.name + '</span>'
            else
            return '<span class="span-legend-item-inactive">' + this.name + '</span>'
        }
    },

    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
    },

    series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
    }, {
        data: [11.9, 31.5, 78.4, 29.2, 44.0, 76.0, 95.6, 48.5, 116.4, 114.1, 35.6, 154.4]
    }]
});
```

```css
.span-legend-active {
    background-color: white;
    border: 1px solid green;
    /* border: none; */
    color: black;
    padding: 3px 7px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 13px;
    
}

.span-legend-item-inactive {
    background-color: white;
    border: 1px solid #cccccc;
    color: #cccccc;
    padding: 3px 7px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 13px;
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="height: 400px"></div>
```

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you don't need to use the legendItemClick event to do that. You can try to change your CSS selectors with:

```
.highcharts-legend-item > span > span {
    (active style)
}
.highcharts-legend-item-hidden > span > span {
    (inactive style)
}
```

Your modified code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/eightball/zb27u8fg).

Comment: Thanks. I think it is a better way of doing it

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:**

I have made a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gowthamrajj/czg9c1fk/1/) for toggling CSS of your legend items.

You can set class to your legend on click like this,

```
events: {
  legendItemClick: function(event) {
                     //console.log(event);
                     if(this.visible)
                       event.target.legendItem.element.firstChild.className = 'span-legend-item-inactive';
                     else
                       event.target.legendItem.element.firstChild.className = 'span-legend-active';
                   }
  }
```

Here, the `this.visible` is boolean variable given by Hightcharts, to denote if the legend is visible or not. Check this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/plotoptions/series-events-legenditemclick/) reference from highcharts website.

If its visible during `onclick`, you can assign your `.span-legend-item-inactive` class to make it disabled. Similarly, if its not visible during `onclick`, you can assign `.span-legend-active` to make it look enabled. You can give space separated class names, if you want to assign more than one class or use `event.target.legendItem.element.firstChild.classList`

Also, Highcharts passes `event` Object to these events functions. You can console it and check for the methods or variables, you can use for your purpose.

Also, `this.color` would give the current series line's color. So you can use this to set your legend color or border color in `labelFormatter` with something like this,

```
return `<span class="span-legend-active" style="border-color:${this.color}">${this.name}</span>`
```

Link to [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gowthamrajj/czg9c1fk/2/).

**Old answer:**

The [labelFormatter()](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/legend.labelFormatter) is not providing any argument for the function, hence clickCounter is undefined.

So dont give the clickCounter to your labelFormatter function, it will take from global scope.

```
   legend: {
        useHTML: true,
        labelFormatter: function () {}
    }
```

Comment: I tried removing the same and it does take from the global scope, but the increment in clickCounter is not reflecting. Hence the logic is not working

Comment: thanks, perfect for me to allow me became my legends in boxes